# Sharepoint 2010 - Which master page is in use

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there anyway I can determin which Master page is currently set as default on a Sharepoint 2010 installation?

Answer (score 7):

look at the settings in `http://<servername>/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`

programmatically you can look at the `CustomMasterUrl` or `MasterUrl` properties of a web.

Comment: To use ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx, Publishing features must first be activated: http://technicallead.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/sharepoint-2010-cannot-find-link-to-master-page-page-layouts/

Answer (score 1):

It is v4.master by default. You can go to VS.NET 2010's Server explorer and add a connection to your Site Collection and check "MasterUrl" and "CustomMasterUrl" properties of the RootWeb of your site collection.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said above, V4.master is the default master page applied to sites. 
you can find this page in c:...\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\V4.master

Here in this blog I have posted how to create & deploy custom master page programatically using VS 2010.

http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-web-content-management.html

-Vighnesh